# Looking for an explanation of how to use PNGlitch

Tags: ruby, command-line, syntax, rubygems, png

I have installed the Ruby environment manager [rbenv](https://gist.github.com/stonehippo/cc0f3098516fb52390f1), Ruby, [RubyGems](https://rubygems.org/pages/download), and [PNGlitch](https://github.com/ucnv/pnglitch) (on macOS). Now how do I use PNGlitch?

The best documentation I have been able to find is on [this page](https://ucnv.github.io/pnglitch/#appendix-a), and here's an example of the syntax given:

**How to use this library: The Simple Way**

```
png = PNGlitch.open '/path/to/your/image.png'
png.glitch do |data|
  data.gsub /\d/, 'x'
end
png.save '/path/to/broken/image.png'
png.close
```

Okay, great. When I insert my file paths, save that code as an .rb file, and open it, I just get:

`test.rb: command not found`

If I paste it directly into Terminal I get:

```
png = PNGlitch.open '/Users/username/Documents/testimage.png'
-bash: png: command not found
ComputerName:~ username$ png.glitch do |data|
>   data.gsub /\d/, 'x'
-bash: png.glitch: command not found
-bash: data: command not found
-bash: data.gsub: command not found
ComputerName:~ username$ end
-bash: end: command not found
ComputerName:~ username$ png.save '/Users/username/Documents/testimage_glitched.png'
-bash: png.save: command not found
ComputerName:~ username$ png.close
```

I also tried the syntax given on [this page](https://www.wvanw.space/?p=294) and entered:

`pnglitch /Users/username/Documents/testimage.png –filter=Sub /Users/username/Documents/testimage_glitched.png`

...this resulted in getting the following message:

```
tried to create Proc object without a block

Usage:
  pnglitch <infile> [--filter=<n>] <outfile>

Options:
  -f, --filter=<n>  Fix all filter types as passed value before glitching.
                    A number (0..4) or a type name (none|sub|up|average|paeth).
  --version         Show version.
  -h, --help        Show this screen.
```

↑ I guess this is the developer's idea of documentation.

Well, trying to follow that example I also did this:

`pnglitch </Users/username/Documents/testimage.png> [--filter=<2>] </Users/username/Documents/testimage_glitched.png>`

...but that only resulted in:

`-bash: syntax error near unexpected token 2`

(I chose 2 because apparently that [corresponds to the "Sub" filter](https://www.wvanw.space/?p=294).)

I tried variants of this syntax as well, including omitting characters `<>` and `[]`.

There must be some assumed knowledge here that I don't have. So what I would like to know is:

1. How can I actually use PNGlitch to glitch a PNG image?
2. How can I use PNGlitch to glitch *all* the PNG images in a folder?

Any additional advice on using different filters would also be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Tip: The angle brackets are there to indicate where your arguments go. They *do not* appear in the actual command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot going on here that needs to be cleared up.

#### Ruby scripts *need* Ruby to run

You can't just paste these into `bash` and expect anything useful to happen.

The usual procedure is one of two variants. Either:

1. Create a `.rb` script, like `example.rb`
2. Run `ruby example.rb` where that's your script name at the end.

Or use the "hash-bang" method:

1. Create a script with `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` as the very first line.
2. Make this script executable with `chmod +x example.rb`
3. Run this script directly, `./example.rb` or whatever path it has.

Note that `example.rb` by itself will not work unless it is in your path, hence the `./` is necessary.

#### Command line example syntax

Here `<name>` has special meaning, where it's just a way of saying *name* as if it had italics or special formatting. On a text-mode terminal it's not practical to add syntax like that, it's limited to ASCII in most cases, so this tradition evolved.

> Within the POSIX shell `>` and `<` have special meaning, they're used to, respectively, redirect input to or from a file. For example, `ls > ls.txt` dumps the output of `ls` into a file called `ls.txt`, while `cat < ls.txt` reads in the contents of `ls.txt` and displays it.

Things like `[name]` mean *optional* arguments, like `[--help]` means the `--help` argument is optional.

> Within the POSIX shell `[` and `]` have special meaning. They can be used in an `if` construct, but more commonly in file wildcards, like `l[abc].txt` means any of `la.txt`, `lb.txt` or `lc.txt`.

Putting this together it's possible to understand the notation used here:

```
pnglitch <infile> [--filter=<n>] <outfile>
```

Where that means `infile` is your "input file" argument, and `outfile` is your "output file" argument, and `--filter` is an optional argument taking `n` as an input.

So you call it like this:

```sh
pnglitch input.png output.png
```

Or with an option, like you did:

```sh
pnglitch testimage.png --filter=sub testimage_glitched.png
```

Though note I've used lower-case `sub` as that's precisely what's in the help output and following casing conventions usually matters.

Comment: Thank you! All that you explained is very helpful. Something is still wrong when I try to run the script though. First thing to mention is that in the filter specification you have an En Dash (U+2013), while what I have on my keyboard is a Hyphen-Minus (U+002D). Not sure if it's a keyboard region thing or what, but anyway both of those characters result in a syntax error. Either `unexpected local variable or method` or `unexpected unary-`. Do you have any idea why? I'm curious, have you installed PNGlitch and is it working for you?

Comment: That was actually a mistake, copied from your example without realizing it. Corrected.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I must have pasted it from somewhere without noticing. I don't know how to type it with my keyboard, and I generally try to avoid using any dashes besides the standard "Hyphen-Minus" for this very reason. But yeah, even after fixing that I still get `syntax error, unexpected unary-, expecting end-of-input`

Comment: It's possible that this is just a buggy gem. It's only version 0.0.3 which is never confidence inspiring.

Comment: Great news! I got it working! It seems PNGlitch doesn't currently work with Ruby 3.x.x I did `rbenv install 2.7.2`, `rbenv global 2.7.2` (the last release before 3), installed RubyGems into it, then did `gem install pnglitch`. Now I can glitch images by typing the syntax you provided into Terminal: `pnglitch testimage.png --filter=sub testimage_glitched.png` I still don't know how to batch process images or fine-tune the parameters, but it's usable! (Accepting answer...)

Comment: One further discovery - many syntax examples examples on [The Art of PNG Glitch](https://ucnv.github.io/pnglitch/) omit this, but the beginning line of the script should be `require 'pnglitch'`, and then *on the following line* `PNGlitch.open(`...etc. If saved in a .rb file, it can be executed.